# How to download and parse JSON from APIs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've done done coding in Google Scripts and can use the `urlFetchApp` function to download and parse any JSON from APIs, but now I'm trying to do this in Node.js and Lambda. Can someone please point me to the right direction on the function to use?

Answer (score 1):

To make HTTP requests, I recommend using [request](https://github.com/request/request) library and for parsing the response you can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Here is an example of how to use them both: https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers